# Postgres: Syntax Error whatever I do

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've just installed Postgres. I managed to create a database and use my user name as the name of the database.

I use the command

```
psql <mydatabase>
```

However now I'm at this point, I can't do anything. 
I tried to type this command for example

```
CREATE TABLE hosts ( type varchar(20), name varchar(20));
```

And I always get a `syntax error symbol C not exist`

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: What do you see after you type `psql mydatabase`? Do you see the psql prompt?

Comment: yes I do, not sure if was clear but the symbol is a bracket

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the statement and the error message from the screen?

Comment: Suggest you add PGAdmin or some other GUI